# Ajax drop down list problem with callback

Tags: ajax

I need a little help here.
In a custom module, I add a little form where you type your zip code, press a button and a drop down list populates (via ajax) with the stores that are close to that zip code so you can choose one of them. The problem is when you click on that button the callback is made but the zip code field remains empty, seems like I missing something that can bring the zipcode value to that part when the  refreshes.
some ideas?? thank you

```
    function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {

       $form['zip_code'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield', 
        '#title' => 'zip code',
        '#size' => 5,
        '#maxlength' => 5,
        '#required' => TRUE
      );

      $form['button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button', 
        '#value' => 'find stores',
        "#limit_validation_errors" => array(),
        "#name" => 'mybutton',
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'reload',
          'wrapper' => 'stores-div',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade'
        )
      );
      $form['select_str'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="stores-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
      );
      if(isset($form_state['values']['zip_code'])) {
        $arr = find_store($form_state['values']['zip_code']); //here is my main problem, $form_state['values']['zip_code']is always empty even after the callback 
      } else {
        $arr[99999] = 'theres none';
      }
      $form['select_str']['stores'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select', 
        '#title' => 'stores near you:',
        '#options' => $arr,
        '#required' => TRUE
      );
      $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send!'),
      );
      return $form;
    }
    function find_store($zc) {
        $fields = array(
                'zc'=>urlencode($zc),
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://somepage.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $arr = array();
        if($result!='none') {
            $explode=explode(',',$result);
            foreach($explode as $value) {
                $stores = explode('|',$value);
                $arr[$stores[0]] = $stores[1];

        }


    } else {
        $arr[99999] ='theres none';
    }
    return $arr;

}
function reload($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['select_str'];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The values will be passed to the callback function `reload` instead of the original form function, therefore you should rebuild the form in your callback function - `reload` and pass back the element:

```
function reload($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form = drupal_rebuild_form('mymodule_form', $form_state, $form);
  return $form['select_str'];
}
```

Comment: thank you, the select field is refreshing good now  but when I choose one option and click the submit button,  the form validator throws me this error "stores near you: field is required" no matter what option I choose

Comment: @Alex Add `#limit_validation_errors => array()` as a property of `$form['button']`, that'll stop the validation from running just for the AJAX request

Comment: @Clive $form['button'] already has that property, the problem is when I'm trying to actually submit the complete form with the store selected.

Comment: @Alex Sorry I missed that in the question...I would've thought you need to pass `$form` in by reference to the `reload()` function: `function reload(&$form, &$form_state) {...`. Otherwise the original form element won't be updated and the value selected will not be a valid one as far as the form API is concerned

Comment: @Clive adding function reload(&$form, &$form_state) makes no difference, still giving me the 'field is required error' like no value was selected

Comment: @Alex I've changed my answer. My original answer probably wasn't the correct method to use. Please see if that helps with validation issues. I assume ur on D7? And your mymodule_form function should be as it was on your question.

Comment: @Baysaa thank you man, everything appears to be working fine now.